# jquery auto open slide menu when page load

Tags: jquery, css

i have an wordpress site and it have menus over there. what i want is this that when some body hover the SITE logo then it's showing the drop down menus.... what i am trying to do is be always open not only when im clicking. it have to load when page get refreshed,

can any body tell that how to do that?

Comment: Just change the css so the menu will be shown.

Comment: @eric i want it to show after the 3 seconds when page get load.

Comment: then edit the css using `.css()` 3 seconds after `document.ready()`

Comment: can you please post code, or an example site.. Very hard to provide credible answers with poor english and no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### .ready() - use this to ensure the object being referenced is in a ready state.

Documentation - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

#### css() - use this to modify the CSS values of a property

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css/

#### Code Example

```
//only execute when the document returns ready
//this can be trivial if your putting the code at the footer
//you may wish to use a self invoking function in that case
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //do something
    $('#somethingcool').css('background-color', 'red');

  //3 seconds = 3000ms
  }, 3000);
});
```

---

Comment: 3 seconds are more like 3000ms not 10800

Comment: yeah just noticed that, haven't had my coffee this morning =P

Comment: please tell me how you calculated that :)

Comment: Remember user he can fire click() event adding a listener on the logo container. Regards.

Comment: in regards to @Firula's comment.. you'd use `$('#clickitem').click(function(){` instead of the `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: @Andy `3*60*60` like i said, havent had my coffee.. spaced the fact that there's `1000ms` in a second lol

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(document).ready(function() {}` to run code after the page loads. You can then use the JQuery delay() function to wait for 3 seconds before calling slideDown on your menu object. Something like this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourMenuID').delay(3000).slideDown(300);
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: +1 for use of delay, i've always used `setTimeout`, yet another way of providing the same result.